# Read string from text file (JFileChooser) and display in TextArea

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I've got some simple app when I want to choose a text file from my disk and display its content in TextArea.

```
 private void fileChooserActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

    try {
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = in.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            textArea.setText(line + "\n");
            line = in.readLine();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

I've tried to do it this way, but it reads only the last line from the text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `textArea.setText(line + "\n");` for each line in your file. So first you write the first line's contents, then you overwrite that with the second line's content, etc. In the end, only the last line's content is in the textArea.

To see all the lines, append the data like this:

```
textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "\n" + line);
```

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Thank you

Comment: You could do it slightly simpler by `textArea.append("\n" + line);`